# list substring (I think thats what it is called) from string output

Tags: powershell

I have a command which gives me the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName XXX -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits -isCollection -ApiVersion 2016-09-01 | select Properties

Properties
----------
@{provisioningState=Succeeded; resourceGuid=XXX; peerings=System.Object[]; authorizations=System.Object[]; serviceProviderProperties=; circuitProvisio...
```

Now I just want to capture the `provisioningState=value` from the properties.

Comment: `... | select -Expand properties | select -Expand provisioningState`

Comment: What exactly do you need? The 'Succeeded' value? You're already using | Select (that is, Select-Object) in your example. Can't you use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help for fetching the provisioningState:

```
$resource =  Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName XXX -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits -isCollection -ApiVersion 2016-09-01 | select -expand Properties
$resource[provisioningState]
```

or

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName XXX -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits -isCollection -ApiVersion 2016-09-01 | select -expand Properties | %{$_.provisioningState}
```

AFAIK select does not work on hash table and properties is a hash table (infering from the output)